# Can some one help me to find the CSS selector for highlighted item

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, css-selectors

Could someone help me to identify the correct csslocator for the second span element in the below image:

[image]

I tried the below locators but was not able to succeed, is there anything wrong with the locator used ?

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("class[onclick='gotoReportView(20, 'ReportSectionc5404625cccfdb7d5563')']")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("Span[onclick='gotoReportView(20, 'ReportSectionc5404625cccfdb7d5563')']")).Click();
```

Comment: The persone who mention this as "-1" please post the correct answer or else the admin need to control these kind of stupid activities on giving permissions to beginners to mark a question as"-1"

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a different way to get to the element that I use a lot. It might be slower, because it does mutliple FindElement(s) calls, but it is so much more readable and understandable.

```
var container = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("items-container"));
var spans = container.FindElements(By.TagName("span"))
spans[1].Click();
```

You find the div and then search for elements within the div and then take the second one to interact with.

Comment: Wow,That was a quick answer and a correct answer,Thank You!.

Comment: But I was hardly looking for a CSSSelector. :(

Answer (score 1):

**Your css locator is wrong:**

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("class[onclick='gotoReportView(20, 'ReportSectionc5404625cccfdb7d5563')']")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("Span[onclick='gotoReportView(20, 'ReportSectionc5404625cccfdb7d5563')']")).Click();
```

**The format for css locator is ,**

1. tag[attribute='value']
2. tag.classname
3. tag#id
4. Tag>Tag  (direct child)
5. tag tag (in direct child , equvalent to /tag//tag in xpath)
6. tag[attribute*='value'] ( Similar to contains in xpath, it search for partial match)
7. tag[attribute^='value'] ( find attribute that start with particular value)

**So the correct css locator is:**

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[onclick=\"gotoReportView(20, \'ReportSectionc5404625cccfdb7d5563\')\"]")).Click();
```

Or

```
 driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[class='item'][onclick=\"gotoReportView(20, \'ReportSectionc5404625cccfdb7d5563\')\"]")).Click();
```

**Note:** you should escape the quotes (\') as there are quotes within the locator

And also use " quotes for the value Eg "[attribute=\"somthing(\'something\')\"]"

**So just use the locator as it is in the DOM, and escape inner quotes using '\'**

Comment: I tryed but its not working fine.Im getting below error.An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: For the 1st one - Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span[onclick='gotoReportView(20, "ReportSectionc5404625cccfdb7d5563")']"}
 Let me try the 2nd one, Any way thank you very much for your valuable effort.

Comment: Same error for the 2nd option too.--An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span[class='item'][onclick='gotoReportView(20, "ReportSectionc5404625cccfdb7d5563")']"}

Comment: Let me look into this

Comment: No isses ,I will stick to Niels van Reijmersdal's replay.

Comment: @ChathuD Could you try this one , i have made a change . This is an interesting question it would be great if you could try and let me know

Comment: i swapped the " and ' , now it is working in my system . Please do try and let me know

Comment: Added more information about css, hope this helps , please try it out